# XOR tool that updates in real time

Tags: hex-editors, bitwise-operators

I am aware that most hex editors allow me to perform all sorts of bit operations, but I am looking for something that satisfies the following:

- Is a hex viewer/editor
- Allows me to XOR a single byte, or a string of bytes (ie: XOR 0x12345678). OR and AND would be nice too.
- Updates in real-time and is "sufficiently fast" for "sufficiently large files". Basically, for 10-20 MB files I don't want to sit there waiting 10-20 seconds.

Does anyone know of such a tool? Or which language would be best to write this in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the second question, that is, to write such a tool with light weight and efficiency, I will suggest C/C++. If you want to write it very fast, then I will suggest C#.net